# How to replace column 3 with column 1 when it has a specific word?

Tags: linux, replace

I have a three column data file which is of the format as below:

```
convicts NP convict
console  JJ <unknown>
apples   NP apple
```

So, here I would like to have the word console in the place where the word "unknown" is.

PS: It is a huge file which contains the word "unknown" multiple number of times. So, wherever the word "unknown" occurs in the third column, I want it to be replaced by it's corresponding 1st column word.

I tried using the command

```
awk ' { $3="unknown"; $3=$1; print } ' <FILENAME>
```

but this replaces the entire 3rd column with the words of the 1st column. Please help with how I can rectify this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to replace `<unknown>` with the corresponding lines first column value:

```
awk '$3=="<unknown>"{$3=$1;} {print};' filename
```